# output getting truncated using winrm

Tags: python, powershell, winrm, pywin

There is a script I am running to get disk level information which given below.

**disk.ps1:**

```bsh
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | % {
    $disk = $_
    $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                  "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                  "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $partitions | % {
        $partition = $_
        $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                  "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
                  "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
        Get-WmiObject -Query $drives | % {
            New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
                Disk   = $disk.SerialNumber
                Letter = $_.DeviceID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I execute the above snippet on the the windows machine itself, the output is:

```
Letter        Disk
------        ----
    H:        XXX_46_0_80987_XXXXX_b2fd_47bb_bc36_aaf4f3029a00
    L:        XXX_46_0_80987_XXXXX_b2fd_47bb_bc36_aaf4f3029a00
    Q:        XXX_46_0_80987_41a13cd9_b2fd_47bb_bc36_aaf4f3029a00
```

Now I am trying to execute the same script using `pywinrm`.

**disk.py:**

```python
complete = <string which is equivalent to above script>
winrm_connector = winrm.Session('*.X.X.X', auth=('XXXX','XXXXXX.1'))
response = winrm_connector.run_ps(complete)
print response.std_out
```

Executing this I am getting output as:

```
Letter      Disk
------      ----
    H:      XXX_46_0_80987_XXXXX_b2fd_47bb_b...
    L:      XXX_46_0_80987_XXXXX_b2fd_47bb_b...
    Q:      XXX_46_0_80987_41a13cd9_b2fd_47bb_b...
```

Please shed some light on whether WinRM is truncating the output or the shell is truncating the output.

I'm thinking the shell is not doing this because when I execute the script using PowerShell I was able to get the entire output.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell automatically truncates wide columns. To avoid that you can use auto-sized columns by piping the data through `Format-Table -AutoSize` in your PowerShell code. Since you're invoking the command via Python, which doesn't know about PowerShell objects, you may also want to convert the `Format-Table` output to a string by piping it through `Out-String` (with a large value for the line length).

```
... | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096
```

Comment: i got that.. but the format-table need to be the part of script execution or inside the script?

Comment: It's PowerShell code, so obviously it needs to be part of your PowerShell code, not your Python code.